# Remote Process Group for NiFi behind NGINX proxy Unauthorized/Anonymous

Tags: apache-nifi, nginx-reverse-proxy, apache-minifi

I have Nifi running behind NGINX reverse proxy. Both are docker containers. I'm developing a flow for MINIFI utilizing Remote Process Group. In future it is expected that MINIFI accesses the remote process group via proxy.
My remote process group works perfectly if I use URL like https://nifi:8443/nifi (without proxy). As soon as I try to use nifi.example.local with port 7443 or 8443 it breaks. Remote Process Group in the GUI says

```
401: Unauthorized with explanation: null.
```

nifi-user.log says

```
2020-11-13 16:30:00,146 INFO [NiFi Web Server-126] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Attempting request for (<anonymous>) GET https://nifi:8443/nifi-api/site-to-site (source ip: 172.23.0.7)
2020-11-13 16:30:00,146 WARN [NiFi Web Server-126] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Rejecting access to web api: Anonymous authentication has not been configured.
2020-11-13 16:30:00,146 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-126] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter
org.apache.nifi.web.security.InvalidAuthenticationException: Anonymous authentication has not been configured.
```

So it seems that the identity info somehow doesn't pass through the proxy. I maybe spoiled something in my nginx.conf but right now it looks like:

```json
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    map $remote_addr $proxy_forwarded_elem {
        # IPv4 addresses can be sent as-is
        ~^[0-9.]+$          "for=$remote_addr";

        # IPv6 addresses need to be bracketed and quoted
        ~^[0-9A-Fa-f:.]+$   "for=\"[$remote_addr]\"";

        # Unix domain socket names cannot be represented in RFC 7239 syntax
        default             "for=unknown";
    }

    map $http_forwarded $proxy_add_forwarded {
        # If the incoming Forwarded header is syntactically valid, append to it
        "~^(,[ \\t]*)*([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?(;([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?)*([ \\t]*,([ \\t]*([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?(;([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+=([!#$%&'*+.^_`|~0-9A-Za-z-]+|\"([\\t \\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF]|\\\\[\\t \\x21-\\x7E\\x80-\\xFF])*\"))?)*)?)*$" "$http_forwarded, $proxy_forwarded_elem";

        # Otherwise, replace it
        default "$proxy_forwarded_elem";
    }

    #redirect to https
    server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host:8443$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 8443 ssl;
        server_name nifi.example.local;
        ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/certs/proxy.cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/proxy.key.pem;
        ssl_password_file /etc/nginx/certs/ssl_passwords.txt;
        proxy_set_header Forwarded $proxy_add_forwarded;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://nifi:8443;
            proxy_set_header X-ProxyScheme https;
            proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost $host;
            proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort 8443;
            proxy_set_header X-ProxiedEntitiesChain $ssl_client_s_dn;
        }
    }

    server {
        # attempt to make proxy nifi connection work
        listen 7443 ssl;
        server_name nifi.example.local;
        ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/certs/proxy.cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/proxy.key.pem;
        ssl_password_file /etc/nginx/certs/ssl_passwords.txt;
        proxy_set_header Forwarded $proxy_add_forwarded;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        ssl_verify_client on;
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/proxy.cert.pem;
        proxy_ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/certs/proxy.cert.pem;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/proxy.key.pem;
        proxy_ssl_password_file /etc/nginx/certs/ssl_passwords.txt;
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/proxy.cert.pem;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://nifi:8443;
            proxy_set_header X-ProxyScheme https;
            proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost nifi.example.local;
            proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort 7443;
            proxy_set_header X-ProxyContextPath /;
            proxy_set_header X-ProxiedEntitiesChain $ssl_client_s_dn;
        }
    }
}
```

nifi.properties looks like:

```py
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Core Properties #
nifi.flow.configuration.file=./conf/flow.xml.gz
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.enabled=true
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.dir=./conf/archive/
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.time=30 days
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.storage=500 MB
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.count=
nifi.flowcontroller.autoResumeState=true
nifi.flowcontroller.graceful.shutdown.period=10 sec
nifi.flowservice.writedelay.interval=500 ms
nifi.administrative.yield.duration=30 sec
# If a component has no work to do (is "bored"), how long should we wait before checking again for work?
nifi.bored.yield.duration=10 millis
nifi.queue.backpressure.count=10000
nifi.queue.backpressure.size=1 GB

nifi.authorizer.configuration.file=./conf/authorizers.xml
nifi.login.identity.provider.configuration.file=./conf/login-identity-providers.xml
nifi.templates.directory=./conf/templates
nifi.ui.banner.text=
nifi.ui.autorefresh.interval=30 sec
nifi.nar.library.directory=./lib
nifi.nar.library.autoload.directory=./extensions
nifi.nar.working.directory=./work/nar/
nifi.documentation.working.directory=./work/docs/components

####################
# State Management #
####################
nifi.state.management.configuration.file=./conf/state-management.xml
# The ID of the local state provider
nifi.state.management.provider.local=local-provider
# The ID of the cluster-wide state provider. This will be ignored if NiFi is not clustered but must be populated if running in a cluster.
nifi.state.management.provider.cluster=zk-provider
# Specifies whether or not this instance of NiFi should run an embedded ZooKeeper server
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=false
# Properties file that provides the ZooKeeper properties to use if <nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start> is set to true
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.properties=./conf/zookeeper.properties


# H2 Settings
nifi.database.directory=./database_repository
nifi.h2.url.append=;LOCK_TIMEOUT=25000;WRITE_DELAY=0;AUTO_SERVER=FALSE

# FlowFile Repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository
nifi.flowfile.repository.wal.implementation=org.apache.nifi.wali.SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog
nifi.flowfile.repository.directory=./flowfile_repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.checkpoint.interval=20 secs
nifi.flowfile.repository.always.sync=false
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.provider.implementation=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.provider.location=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key=
nifi.flowfile.repository.retain.orphaned.flowfiles=true

nifi.swap.manager.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.FileSystemSwapManager
nifi.queue.swap.threshold=20000

# Content Repository
nifi.content.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.FileSystemRepository
nifi.content.claim.max.appendable.size=1 MB
nifi.content.repository.directory.default=./content_repository
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.retention.period=7 days
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.usage.percentage=50%
nifi.content.repository.archive.enabled=true
nifi.content.repository.always.sync=false
nifi.content.viewer.url=../nifi-content-viewer/
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.provider.implementation=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.provider.location=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key=

# Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.provenance.WriteAheadProvenanceRepository
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.provider.implementation=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.provider.location=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key=

# Persistent Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.directory.default=./provenance_repository
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.time=30 days
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.size=10 GB
nifi.provenance.repository.rollover.time=10 mins
nifi.provenance.repository.rollover.size=100 MB
nifi.provenance.repository.query.threads=2
nifi.provenance.repository.index.threads=2
nifi.provenance.repository.compress.on.rollover=true
nifi.provenance.repository.always.sync=false
# Comma-separated list of fields. Fields that are not indexed will not be searchable. Valid fields are:
# EventType, FlowFileUUID, Filename, TransitURI, ProcessorID, AlternateIdentifierURI, Relationship, Details
nifi.provenance.repository.indexed.fields=EventType, FlowFileUUID, Filename, ProcessorID, Relationship
# FlowFile Attributes that should be indexed and made searchable.  Some examples to consider are filename, uuid, mime.type
nifi.provenance.repository.indexed.attributes=
# Large values for the shard size will result in more Java heap usage when searching the Provenance Repository
# but should provide better performance
nifi.provenance.repository.index.shard.size=500 MB
# Indicates the maximum length that a FlowFile attribute can be when retrieving a Provenance Event from
# the repository. If the length of any attribute exceeds this value, it will be truncated when the event is retrieved.
nifi.provenance.repository.max.attribute.length=65536
nifi.provenance.repository.concurrent.merge.threads=2


# Volatile Provenance Respository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.buffer.size=100000

# Component Status Repository
nifi.components.status.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.status.history.VolatileComponentStatusRepository
nifi.components.status.repository.buffer.size=1440
nifi.components.status.snapshot.frequency=1 min

# Site to Site properties
nifi.remote.input.host=nifi
nifi.remote.input.secure=true
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=10000
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
nifi.remote.input.http.transaction.ttl=30 sec
nifi.remote.contents.cache.expiration=30 secs

# web properties #
nifi.web.http.host=
nifi.web.http.port=
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.https.host=nifi
nifi.web.https.port=8443
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=nifi:8443,nifi.example.local:8443,nifi.example.local:7443,nifi.example.local,nifi
nifi.web.max.content.size=
nifi.web.max.requests.per.second=30000
nifi.web.should.send.server.version=true

# security properties #
nifi.sensitive.props.key=
nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
nifi.sensitive.props.provider=BC
nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys=

nifi.security.keystore=/opt/certs/nifi-keystore.jks
nifi.security.keystoreType=JKS
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=secret
nifi.security.keyPasswd=secret
nifi.security.truststore=/opt/certs/nifi-truststore.jks
nifi.security.truststoreType=JKS
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=secret
nifi.security.user.authorizer=managed-authorizer
nifi.security.allow.anonymous.authentication=false
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=ldap-provider
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.url=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.certificate=

# OpenId Connect SSO Properties #
nifi.security.user.oidc.discovery.url=
nifi.security.user.oidc.connect.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.read.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.id=
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.secret=
nifi.security.user.oidc.preferred.jwsalgorithm=
nifi.security.user.oidc.additional.scopes=
nifi.security.user.oidc.claim.identifying.user=

# Apache Knox SSO Properties #
nifi.security.user.knox.url=
nifi.security.user.knox.publicKey=
nifi.security.user.knox.cookieName=hadoop-jwt
nifi.security.user.knox.audiences=

# Identity Mapping Properties #
# These properties allow normalizing user identities such that identities coming from different identity providers
# (certificates, LDAP, Kerberos) can be treated the same internally in NiFi. The following example demonstrates normalizing
# DNs from certificates and principals from Kerberos into a common identity string:
#
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.pattern.dn=^CN=(.*?), OU=(.*?), O=(.*?), L=(.*?), ST=(.*?), C=(.*?)$
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.value.dn=$1@$2
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.transform.dn=NONE
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.pattern.kerb=^(.*?)/instance@(.*?)$
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.value.kerb=$1@$2
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.transform.kerb=UPPER

# Group Mapping Properties #
# These properties allow normalizing group names coming from external sources like LDAP. The following example
# lowercases any group name.
#
# nifi.security.group.mapping.pattern.anygroup=^(.*)$
# nifi.security.group.mapping.value.anygroup=$1
# nifi.security.group.mapping.transform.anygroup=LOWER

# cluster common properties (all nodes must have same values) #
nifi.cluster.protocol.heartbeat.interval=5 sec
nifi.cluster.protocol.heartbeat.missable.max=8
nifi.cluster.protocol.is.secure=false

# cluster node properties (only configure for cluster nodes) #
nifi.cluster.is.node=false
nifi.cluster.node.address=d4a1805d84e3
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=10
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=50
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.max.concurrent.requests=100
nifi.cluster.firewall.file=
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=5 mins
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=

# cluster load balancing properties #
nifi.cluster.load.balance.host=
nifi.cluster.load.balance.port=6342
nifi.cluster.load.balance.connections.per.node=1
nifi.cluster.load.balance.max.thread.count=8
nifi.cluster.load.balance.comms.timeout=30 sec

# zookeeper properties, used for cluster management #
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=
nifi.zookeeper.connect.timeout=10 secs
nifi.zookeeper.session.timeout=10 secs
nifi.zookeeper.root.node=/nifi

# Zookeeper properties for the authentication scheme used when creating acls on znodes used for cluster management
# Values supported for nifi.zookeeper.auth.type are "default", which will apply world/anyone rights on znodes
# and "sasl" which will give rights to the sasl/kerberos identity used to authenticate the nifi node
# The identity is determined using the value in nifi.kerberos.service.principal and the removeHostFromPrincipal
# and removeRealmFromPrincipal values (which should align with the kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal and kerberos.removeRealmFromPrincipal
# values configured on the zookeeper server).
nifi.zookeeper.auth.type=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeRealmFromPrincipal=

# kerberos #
nifi.kerberos.krb5.file=

# kerberos service principal #
nifi.kerberos.service.principal=
nifi.kerberos.service.keytab.location=

# kerberos spnego principal #
nifi.kerberos.spnego.principal=
nifi.kerberos.spnego.keytab.location=
nifi.kerberos.spnego.authentication.expiration=12 hours

# external properties files for variable registry
# supports a comma delimited list of file locations
nifi.variable.registry.properties=

# analytics properties #
nifi.analytics.predict.enabled=false
nifi.analytics.predict.interval=3 mins
nifi.analytics.query.interval=5 mins
nifi.analytics.connection.model.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.status.analytics.models.OrdinaryLeastSquares
nifi.analytics.connection.model.score.name=rSquared
nifi.analytics.connection.model.score.threshold=.90
nifi.remote.route.http.nginx.when=${X-ProxyHost:equals('nifi.example.local')}
nifi.remote.route.http.nginx.hostname=nifi.example.local
nifi.remote.route.http.nginx.port=7443
nifi.remote.route.http.nginx.secure=true
```

Can you please suggest what could be the reason and how the problem can be fixed.

Comment: I don't know anything about nginx, but seems like the client certificate is not making it through the proxy so there is no identity by the time it reaches nifi

Comment: That's definitely the case. However, before that I managed to make ListenHTTP and InvokeHTTP working with HTTPS and all the identities and certificates worked fine. For Site-2-site communication there are also examples available on how presumably to make it work on standalone machines or clusters. I followed these examples but likely missed something and failed.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Sorry, no solution with Remote Process Groups was found. At that point we ended up with pure HTTPs Listeners instead of Remote Process Groups.